# Vornado 233 Fan squeaks during startup period: How to diagnose / remedy?

Tags: fans

A [Vornado 233](https://www.amazon.com/Vornado-233B-High-Velocity-Whole-Room-Circulator/product-reviews/B000E0XQBG) fan squeaks when started for a few minutes.  After a steady state is reached, the squeaking halts.  If the angle of the fan is set to vertical it does not squeak at startup.

Is the remedy to simply to disassemble the housing to gain access to the shaft and lubricate the shaft?  I thought it would be best to ask so as to avoid introducing new problems.

I am hoping that someone with experience with maintaining similar desk / floor fans will comment with actionable insight as to what to look for and correct.  Thank you

[image]

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it is not about home improvement, but about small product repair.

Comment: @RMDman  Please advise a better forum to post this question?

Comment: Your bearing is the problem, try with few drops of oil

Comment: @Ruskes Post your comment as an answer to receive credit.    Success! :)

Comment: Glad it worked ...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Usually it is the shaft and the bearing.

Clean it and drop few droplets of oil.